# Is this considered hard coding?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I have an assignment where we need to take a string, s, and a position, pos, and I need to "gather" all integers at the position. For example, saying 3 abcdef123 should output abc123def (the integers begin at position 3). The main where these parameters are accepted is not pictured.

An example input might look like this:

> 5 ab1cdefgh (the 1 moves to the 5th index)
>
> 6 1abcdefgh (the 1 moves to the 6th index)
>
> 8 1abcdefgh (the 1 moves to the end)
>
> 8 abcdefgh1 (the 1 doesn't move)
>
> 0 1abcdefgh
>
> -1 (quit)

```
void gatherDigits(std::string& s, const int pos) {

int ints = 1;
int size = s.size();

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    if (std::isdigit(s.at(i))) {
        ints++;
    }
}

s = ""; 
char letter;
char l;
int count = 0;
for (letter = 'a'; letter <= 'z'; letter++) {
    if (count == pos) {
        l = letter;
        break;
    }
    s = s + letter;
    count++;
}   

for (int i = 1; i < ints; i++) {

    if (i == 10) {
        s = s + std::to_string(0);
    }
    else {

        s = s + std::to_string(i);
    }
}   

for (int i = pos + ints; i < size + 1; i++) {
    s = s + l;
    l++;
   }
}
```

However, I've run into a predicament. I'm not sure if this is considered hard coding (we are explicitly instructed not to hard code). The only variables we are allowed to use is int and char, which is why I have it set up this way. Additionally, all input examples are lower case a-z and 0-9 ints. Our code must run in O(n^2) time.

A more difficult input might look like this:

> 6 12ab3cdefghij456klm7n8op9q0

The suggested solution involves utilizing swap statements. My code meets all other requirements except for its lack of swap statements. In the end, I am just asking: does this qualify as hard coding?

Comment: "Hard coding" would for example be to put the input values inside the program as values, and not read them from the user. Then those values would be "hard coded". Hard coded values can't change at run-time.

Comment: The only think I see that might be considered "hard-coding" is that magic number 10 in the "if (i == 10)" line.  I'm not sure why that is there.

Comment: Also note that your program might fail on 0.001% (or something) of all computers, namely all that don't use the ASCII alphabet. The C++ specification only says that encoded digits are contiguous, letters don't have to be. This will allow C compilers to work on systems that, for example, uses the [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC) alphabet, which have gaps between the letters. It's really nothing you should worry about now, ASCII is prevalent and if you need to code for a system that doesn't use ASCII you will know.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner, its because the tenth integer needs to be a zero, not a 10. The way my code is set up it would concatenate a 10. I will probably try to work out a better solution, but that's the current situation.

Comment: Are you certain that the digits and the letters will always be in that order? Because if so, you certainly don't need O(n^2). Also, if you don't have to preserve the order of the letters and digits, there's a perfectly good O(n) solution.

Comment: @hubert: that was my first thought, too but it's not correct, is it? The digits need to *start* at the indicated position; that only guarantees that there is an integer at or just before the indicated position.

Comment: @hubert: the first example says "the integers begin at position 3". I'd use rotate after the two stable_partitions.

Comment: I would not consider this hard coding. One thing that you could improve the code is to use the `isalpha`and `isdigit` functions from <cctype> to check the character types.

Comment: I just realized that "hard code" and "hardcode" map to two very different meanings in my mind.

Comment: @HubertApplebaum the last example would have a result of:  abcdef1234567890ghijklmnopq (where the integers start at the 6th index). I agree its a weird gray area as I am clearly restructuring the string based on indexes, but all examples given my code works - I guess I'll have to inquire with the instructor.

Comment: Additionally, the goal is to be memory efficient. This is my first course in C++ so I have no idea how to verify that. From the assignment: "Since the objective is to be memory efficient, solutions that use intermediate
strings (or buffers) to solve this problem (Using integer or character variables is fine but not arrays, strings, vectors, etc) will be assigned only a partial score"

Comment: @rici here's a screenshot of sample inputs: http://imgur.com/a/R2Tfv

Comment: @HubertApplebaum: For your amusement, here's the O(n) rearrangement I threw together last night. It doesn't preserve order of the letters and digits, but has a certain elegance. Although it's based on the Lomuto partition algorithm, it's sufficiently different that I don't think that it can be done with the standard library. (The second part could be, but by that point, why bother :) ) http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/765f532faa26ac84

Comment: @Rob: It's unfortunate that your professor's examples all have the letters and digits in a particular order, since it distracts from the actual problem description. Personally, I think you should not rely on it (and that's the gist of the answer, as well). By the way, there is an O(n log n) solution, so if you really want to excel, you could try to figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you did hard-code is the expectation that the letters in the string are starting with `a` and build a sequence `abcd....` and your digits form `1234...`. Whether or no that will be considered hard-coded by your supervisor I can't say, but it certainly makes your code pretty inflexible and I'd only do that if those properties are explicitly stated in the problem description.

The part about swapping likely refers to swapping around the actual characters to the proper places in the string instead of tearing down the whole string and creating a new one, which is only possible with the above mentioned assumptions.

As hinted in the comments, if you are allowed to use standard algorithms, you can greatly simplify and generalize your solution. One possibility would e.g. be:

```
void gatherDigits(std::string& s, const int pos) {
    //moves all digits to the start of the range and returns the number of digits
    int cnt = std::stable_partition(s.begin(), s.end(), ::isdigit) - s.begin();

    //make sure we don't write past the end of the string
    assert(pos+cnt < s.size()); 

    //rotates the string such that the digits start at the correct place
    std::rotate(s.begin(), s.begin() + cnt, s.begin() + pos + cnt);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response - I'll have to inquire about the characters and digits. Would my original code be considered memory efficient? We're not supposed to use any variables besides int and char (in order to be memory efficient), but we're allowed to have O(n^2) runtime.

Comment: @HuberAppleBaum: Thanks for the corrections, but why did you remove the `std` namespace before `isdigit`?

Comment: @Rob: I don't see the connection between using int and char variables and being memory efficent, but I'd guess your solution is about as memory efficeint and fast as it gets. My solution is somewhat suboptimal in regard to memory efficiency, as `std::stable_partition` will usually allocate an extra memory buffer. However, both solutions solve different problems, and I didn't make any measurements anyway.

Comment: @MikeMB: Perhaps he removed `std` from `std::isdigit` because it doesn't compile :-).

Comment: @rici: On what compiler? What header did you include?

Comment: @MikeMB: gcc 5.3 (coliru) / `#include <cctype>`: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8c0dfde75828c7b9

Comment: @rici: Interesting. Seems like libstdc++ (and probably libc++, but not VC++'s standard library) indirectly includes `<locale>`, which introduces a template function of the same name, so the compiler can't decide which function to use leading to the compiler error you are seeing.

Comment: @MikeMB: Yeah, I tried it with libc++ as well. I don't have VC++.

Comment: Yes, I removed the `std` prefix otherwise you have ambiguity. You could either fix that with a lambda that forwards to `std::isdigit`, or cast it to the correct function pointer, or call the C version, which I did. Feel free to change to whatever version you prefer (but this one is the shortest).

Comment: @Hubert: Thanks, I agree that this is the best solution and will leave it as it is.